# Excel - sum row if column names match criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose we have a few sheets with numbers (for example, quarterly sales data for different geos). We want to SUM different columns for each sheet. Those columns which should be summed for each sheet are stored in a separate sheet as follows:

[image]

So, for instance in the first sheet we wanna sum columns with headers {"Beta", "Delta", "Foxtro"} etc. So it should looks like:

[image]

I'm trying to play with functions like SUM, INDEX and MATCH:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:CZ2199;2;MATCH("Alpha";A1:CZ1;0)))
```

But instead of "Alpha" I would like to make a reference to an another sheet with multiple MATCH criteria as specified above.

It is also possible to make changes in the 'columns to be summed" sheet as follows:

[image]

and then write SUM formulas in respective sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your first layout you could use in `H2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(SeperateSheet!B:G,MATCH(1,SeperateSheet!A:A,0),)="X")*B2:G2)
```

Where `1` in the `MATCH` stands for the 1st sheet you use the formula in. In the second sheet you use `2`.

***Note:** Change comma delimiters to semi-colon if you so require.*